# meta specific Badge idea

Tags: discussion, badges

I would love to see a Meta Badge that pegs you for having more rep on meta than on the main SO site.

Talks about talking about code much more than asking or answering questions about code.

Not sure what it would be called.

Ideas?

Comment: Finally, a badge Jon Skeet can't earn.

Comment: I was about to complain for exactly that reason. Time for 1300x 500pt bounty questions on SO ;)

Comment: Gold badge of shame if it's your highest out of the entire trilogy.

Comment: You can never beat a cat at a staring contest. But I'm going to try.

Comment: If you stand with your back to the sun, you will always best the cat at the staring contest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Not sure what it would be called.
>
> Ideas?

[Omphaloskepsis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omphaloskepsis)

Answer (score 13):

How about you call it the "Gym Teacher" badge:

> "Those who can, do. Those who can't
>   do, teach. Those who can't teach,
>   teach gym."

Comment: Made me laugh out loud. I like it.

Answer (score 2):

[Cruiser](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2000/11/18/the_bastard_hits_cruise_control/):

> I hate the company cruiser. And every company has one - the person who doesn't really have a job outside of collecting stats on how winnable the Solitaire game on their desktop is. But so as to disguise this fact, they spend most of their time out of their office "working" with others.

Answer (score 1):

#### Watercooler

For those who rep higher on meta and talk about the S[O|F|U] trilogy more than they actually spend repping up on the sites.

Constantly hitting refresh for meta questions is the equivalent of the constant refilling of the paper cup.

Answer (score 0):

You could call it **Manager** or any variant like Technical Manager or Middle Manager - something that implies that you have done your time on implementation side of IT, but have since moved 'up' to manage, and now spend too much time talking about development but not actually developing.